# Is it haram to work for a credit union in USA? I'm a Network/Systems Admin

Tags: halal-haram

Our sources of income range from lending mortgage money, interest earned from home equity loans, car loans, interest earned from credit cards, maintenance fees etc. I'm not directly involved in dealing or updating interest rate. But since I've heard from people who live here in USA that interest on mortgage is halal because you become owner after certain amount of time. if you were not to give mortgage you're going to give rent and consider mortgage as you're paying some money on top of rent to become owner of the house in 30 years. I'm asking two questions here.

1. Is job is halal?
2. what's the authentic stance on

Answer (score 0):

Most finance careers, including accounting, actuarial, investment banking, investment management and others involve working with debt. In western societies, this involves riba (interest) which is forbidden in Islam. Working in any place that deals with interest and helping these firms is haram